# Selecting sub field in the nested object using TypeScript Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to select an object array of nested object inside an array of o

```
export interface IDetails{
           _id?: string;
           order?: number;
           detaildesc?: string;
         }

    resl:any[];
    var data={
         locations: string;
         id: string;
         ordermain: number;
         value: string;
         details :[IDetails]
        }


I am trying to get list of all "order" under details:

    resl = this.data.forEach(a=> { a.details.map(x=>x.order});
```

I'm getting the following error:

> type void is not assignable to type any[] for `resl` .

When I just make `var resl`, i get `undefined error`.

Please let me know how to fix that so I get array of `details.order`
I checked around on the stackoverflow for possible solution couldnt find one that solves the issue.

Thanks

Comment: try to replace forEach cause it doesn't return anything, `let result = this.data.details.map(row=> { row.order});`

Comment: @styopdev I cant do this.data.details.map ....because of I believe details is Interface because of it details has message details does not exist on type IDetails[ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all orders with

```
    var ordersArr = data.map(x => {
        return x.details.map(y => {
            return y.order;
        });
    });
```

`ordersArr` would be an `array of array`. To flatten it youcan write

```
    var result = [].concat.apply([], ordersArr);
```

`result` would be array of all order values

You can also do the same thing with `forEach` instead of using `map`

```
    this.data.forEach(x => {
        x.details.forEach(y => {
            if (y.order) {
                this.resl.push(y.order);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am getting red line under a saying [ts] can not find a

Comment: It does run but returns empty array. I am wondering if it has to do with not all values of order exist. Some order values are null

Comment: I can see the values now in the resl using browser tools. However when I use it in select using <option *ngFor="let ord of resl" [value]="ord.order'>{{ord.order}}</option> i get order not defined error? Thanks for your help finally getting some where

Comment: I am assuming the data object is coming from a service call. You need to assign  an empty array to resl before pushing new values to it. You can write `this.resl = [];` in your **constructor**

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be not correct, so I assumed this is what you expected

```
export interface IDetails {
    _id?: string;
    order?: number;
    detaildesc?: string;
}

export class Something {
    resl: any[];
    data: {
        locations: string;
        id: string;
        ordermain: number;
        value: string;
        details: IDetails[];
    }[];

    aFunction() {
        this.resl = this.data.map(a => { a.details.map(x => x.order});
    }
}
```

and `map`, not `forEach` will returned a transformed array